# google cloud pub sub multiple subscriber for the same message with the same subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, event-driven

I am working on implementing event driven using GCP Pub/Sub.

I have a topic called orders, and that topic will have a subscription named `orderPlacedSubscription` I have two services that want to listen to all messages for this subscription and perform different actions,
so I have paymentService and notificationService, the paymentService will listen to each message filtered by `orderPlacedSubscription` and process the payment as well as the notification service will listen to the same message and send a notification.

#### My question

- does pub-sub support having two subscribers related to one subscription and both receive messages and acknowledge them separately?
- In case if each subscriber can acknowledge the message separately without affecting the other subscriber, does google cloud pub-sub support retry for different subscribers in case of failure from one subscriber?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a subscription can have multiple subscriber clients.

In a subscription workflow, if a message is not acknowledged by a subscriber, Pub/Sub will attempt to redeliver the outstanding message. In the process of redelivering the outstanding message, Pub/Sub holds back and tries not to deliver the outstanding message to any other subscriber on the same subscription. Once the outstanding message is acknowledged it can be  delivered to other subscribers.

You can refer [subscription workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQ9_Xur2aM4&t=114s) and this  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#subscription-workflow) for more information.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, I have another question

is there a possible way to process one message at a time for each client

for example

I have a payment topic and have three instances of payment service and these instances are connected to pub-sub, what I want is each message go to one instance without going to another one because if more than one instance received the same message it will duplicate payment which is invalid behavior, I know that this could be resolved using idempotency, but what I mean is to make pub-sub works as a queue, send the message to only one listener

Comment: Hi @tareksalem, According to Stackoverflow best practices, I would advise you to open a new thread for any new additional questions. It increases the question visibility and the chances of finding answers.

Comment: The answer is not true. Please, check the PubSub architecture in the section "The Basics of a Publish/Subscribe services". Your scenario is a subscription with two subscribers. Here messages will be processed by one subscriber only. https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture

There are cases were both subscribers will process the message. This is because of their Pull-behaviour in which both subscribers have a buffer containing the same message.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983777/google-pubsub-python-multiple-subscriber-clients-receiving-duplicate-messages

Comment: @Matthias thanks for pointing out the official docs, I needed to confirm this too: messages are load balanced among subscribers on the same suscription.

Answer (score 1):

Pub/Sub will send the same message to all subscriptions for a given topic, for each subscription it will send the message to one subscriber, the message gets deleted once at least one subscriber acknowledges the message.

This means you can't have multiple subscribers subscribe to the same subscription and have them all process the same message.

[Link to documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#data_plane_-_the_life_of_a_message)